# 301 Redirect in IIS Web.config file

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis-7.5

I have a client where I need to make a HTTP 301 redirection from certain pages so they will get redirected to specific dir. I need to use regex. I also need to redirect non-WWW domain to WWW. So I need two redirections.

I've tried to add this (within existing `<system.webServer>` node):

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Non-WWW to WWW" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Sadly, it throws a HTTP 500 straight into my face. I've followed [this article](http://knowledge.freshpromo.ca/seo-tools/301-redirect.php#canonicaliis).

Any help highly appreciated. I never worked on IIS/ASP.net earlier.

**Server:**
[image]

Comment: did you install the URL Rewrite Module?

Comment: @Cerveser the problem is, I have no access to the server and it's configuration. I only have FTP access and `Web.config` file

Comment: If you can't install the module on the server this won't work.
One work around is to add Application_PreSendRequestHeaders() in Global.asax file and in it set the Context.Response.StatusCode = 301 if Context.Request.Path mathes the RegEx